# Why does the @Many side in a @OneToMany relationship require a reference to the @One side?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I just spent two hours pulling my hair out, wondering why the @Many side in a @OneToMany relationship always contained a null id value for the owner. 
I have two Hibernate entities, User and Purchase. A User can have many purchases, and a purchase can only belong to one user. The following is a snippet of my code

//On the Entity User

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Purchase> purchases = new HashSet<Purchase>();
```

//On the Entity Purchase

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private User user;
```

Now, when I added a new Purchase to the the User's set 'purchases', I realized the Id of the user does NOT automatically link up to the respective Purchase. I have to manually call the method setUser(User user) here:

//In the User class

```
    Purchase purchase = new Purchase();
    purchase.setUser(this);
    purchases.add(purchase);
```

Why is the second line necessary?

Comment: Because the Many side is the owning side of the association, which is the side of the association that  Hibernate considers to know if the association exists or not.

Comment: It's been a while since working with JPA and such stuff, but I'm pretty sure that this theoretically work like you explain...        If I remember right this should be the Line that fixes your problem  
 (Go to the link, since this problem is not that easy explained) `@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID",referencedColumnName="CUST_ID")` https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077819/java-se/understanding-jpa-part-2-relationships-the-jpa-way.html

Answer (score 0):

You will need a separate function to link user to other parts of your program.  I don't know what the program consists of, but make sure you have a getter function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit your transaction so that Hibernate can fill the `user` field for you automatically. Otherwise, Hibernate cannot know when your entity is ready to be committed to the database.